# How to select what data is serialized in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a class like so:

```
class Foo {
    public $a;
    public $b;
    public $c;
}
```

When I `serialize()` an instance of `Foo` I do not wish for `$c` to be serialized.

Furthermore, when I `unserialize()` an instance of `Foo`, I want to be able to initialize `$c` with a value using some code.

How do I do this?

Comment: Check here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Foo {
    public $a = 1;
    public $b = 2;
    public $c = 3;

    function __sleep() {
        return array('a', 'b');
    }
    function __wakeup() {
        $this->c = 4;
    }
}
$foo = new Foo();

var_dump(unserialize(serialize($foo)));
```

outputs

```
object(Foo)#2 (3) {
  ["a"]=>
  int(1)
  ["b"]=>
  int(2)
  ["c"]=>
  int(4)
}
```